# InputDataError Amazon MSW Java

Tags: java, amazon-mws

I'm trying to download a report with Amazon MWS Java samples. I made the request report and then I made the get report request list. The answer is that it's *DONE* but when I'm trying to call the getReport I'm getting this error:
Caught Exception: InputDataError
Response Status Code: 400
Error Code: InputDataError
Error Type: Sender
The keys and IDs are the same as in other requests that work. I'm getting the Report ID from this answer which I receive from get report request list:

```
GetReportRequestListResponse
    GetReportRequestListResult
        HasNext
            false
        ReportRequestInfo
            ReportRequestId
                74259017632
            ReportType
                _GET_XML_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_ORDER_DATE_
            StartDate
                2018-01-31T22:00:00Z
            EndDate
                2018-02-01T22:00:00Z
            SubmittedDate
                2018-04-11T08:10:44Z
            CompletedDate
                2018-04-11T08:10:54Z
            ReportProcessingStatus
                _DONE_
    ResponseMetadata
        RequestId
            9d7668b4-8568-4522-aefc-1bc72f33e20d
```

And this is how I set my report ID:

```
GetReportRequest request = new GetReportRequest();
request.setMerchant( merchantId );
request.setReportId( "74259017632" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

74259017632 is your requestID.

You need to send your reportID.

So there are 3 steps:

1. GetReportRequestList for _GET_XML_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_ORDER_DATE_
2. GetReportList for 74259017632 (this will give you the reportid)
3. GetReport for the reportID

Comment: Thanks! My response didn't provide ReportRequestedId so I had to put it and then take the ID.

Comment: 3 requests to get your inventory... Amazon needs to rebuild their API